# \debug\stableIds.txt: error: failed to open: the data is invalid. (13)

Tags: android, android-studio

Someone, please give some suggestions on this error.

android resource linkage failed:

\debug\stableIds.txt: error: failed to open: the data is invalid. (13).

Answer (score 14):

Disable the antivirus. That actually helped me. I had all perms granted to AS, but for whatever reason, the antivirus was the culprit here.

Comment: i already turned off "file sheild" and "behaviour sheild" on AVG, but  AVG was still cucking AS from doing it's job... quietly.... only after i restarted my computer twice did AVG ask me if i wanted to block AAPT.exe from doing it's job.

Comment: This helped me too, turned off avast and before the app ran , it started downloading a file which was probably getting blocked by the antivirus

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was adding the `.gradle` folder (`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.gradle`) to the anti-virus exceptions list.

Comment: This fixed it for me! While turning off AV did not fix it (for some reason....).